# How to demonstrate the ability to represent your university at international meetings? (postdoc application form)

Tags: application, postdocs, job-search

I was applying for a postdoc position and I came across this sentence in the online supporting statement.

> Ability to represent X University and the consortium at national and
> international meetings related to the project.

I really don't know to answer this without being a bit repetitive. Does this mean I should talk about my past presentations at international conferences? Because I have already talked about this before. I was also a member of the organizing committee of many scientific events, but this highlights my ability to work collaboratively within a team. Any ideas?

Comment: International conferences are good. Better is if you can state that you actually represented projects at consortia. Not necessarily a must, a stand-in might suffice.

Comment: I'm only using 1 sections to respond to these paragraphs. Besides to this online supporting statement, they're also asking for a covering letter that should highlight the same skills. It's a bit too much tbh..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ideas about what is being asked seem to be correct. But rather than being repetitive, perhaps it is enough to just refactor the entire application, moving some statements from other sections into this one.

But the section need not be long if you say something like "As I wrote in my SoP, my experience and commitment to ..."

Don't leave it blank, of course, in case someone is mostly just interested in that section, but don't be boring. Think of the application as a whole and not as just a bunch of parts.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have been looking at this section for more than 2hrs cause I know that being boring and repetitive could be a trap I need to pay attention to..